What the stern-gerlach experiment would look like for tensor-product observable?
The experiment says, that having the $Z$ observable and a qubit, we can have outcomes $+1$ and $-1$. Suppose we have more than one qubit, and build an observable like $O = 3Z_1 + 5Z_3 + 2Z_4$. It also seems pretty straightforward, as I just pass the qubits / particles one by one through magnetic field, scale and sum the individual outcomes.
However, I can't imagine how the experiment would look like for a tensor product observable, like $O = Z_1\otimes Z_2$. What is the meaning / physical interpretation of the tensor product observable in this case? I know all the linear algebra calculations, but how the $Z_1\otimes Z_2$ magnetic field would look like, and why would it produce, e.g. $-1$ outcome for the particle $|01\rangle$?
